# Prevent Vimeo redirect to browser in iOS app

Tags: ios, iframe, vimeo

I'm embedding a page containing a Vimeo iframe within an iOS app page. The page should just load within the app browser but instead redirects the user to the Safari browser and loads the Vimeo video there. If I repoen the app, the page has loaded correctly, except for the content of the iframe.

I've tried using the actual destination URL of the vimeo video eg.

https://player.vimeo.com/video/12345678?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&color=ffffff&loop=1

but there are still some redirects happening in the background causing the video to load in the browser not in the app

Has anyone had this problem before or know how to fix?

Thanks